Can I prevent form submiting on enter key in Devextreme Angular DataGrid form?
I have a complex DataGrid form in my application with a lot of different fields including the text area. Whenever i try to press enter on any of text related fields, form tries to submit, and then the validation messages pop-up. Can I somehow rewrite the enter key behavior for all fields?
I tried event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault() with (onEnterKey) event in different places, but nothing seems to work. It would be great if there were at least a property for either datagrid, or form to prevent this save action on enter key press.
This is devextreme demo code from their page. I have very similar construction.
<div id="data-grid-demo">
  <dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    keyExpr="ID"
    [showBorders]="true"
  >
    <dxo-paging [enabled]="false"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-editing
      mode="form"
      [allowUpdating]="true"
      [allowAdding]="true"
      [allowDeleting]="true"
    >
    </dxo-editing>

    <dxi-column dataField="Prefix" caption="Title" [width]="70"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="FirstName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="LastName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Position" [width]="170"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="StateID" caption="State" [width]="125">
      <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="states" displayExpr="Name" valueExpr="ID">
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date"> </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Notes" [visible]="false">
      <dxo-form-item
        [colSpan]="2"
        editorType="dxTextArea"
        [editorOptions]="{ height: 100 }"
      >
      </dxo-form-item>
    </dxi-column>
  </dx-data-grid>
</div>


do you have a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Just updated the question with their demo code. My is very similar to this.

check if you have a button. By defect, in Angular, the buttons are type "submit" (instead of type="button"), so each ENTER make submit

Those button may be the problem, but they are built in those data-grid forms by default. The only change i can do is to listen to onSave event. But it won't change anything.

you might also consider client-side validations so you can allow enter-submit functionality.  The validations can handle cancelling the submission.

i've found this working which might help you. You can try & let me know if it serves your purpose.
Add onKeyDown function on your data-grid. Something like this,
 <dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    keyExpr="ID"
    [showBorders]="true"
    (onKeyDown)="onKeyDownFunction($event)"
  >

then on your *.ts file
onKeyDownFunction(e: any) {
    if (e.event.key === "Enter") {
      e.event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

